# problem with sources list, apt-get not working properly

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I think something is quite wrong with my sources lists.

`apt-get update` isn't working and I can't install anything, every package can't be found. Here is some output from my terminal that I hope is helpful.

```
bleakley
/etc/apt
≈:≈ ls
apt.conf.d     sources.list.d     trustdb.gpg  trusted.gpg.d
preferences.d  sources.list.save  trusted.gpg  trusted.gpg~
```

`cat sources.list.save` give me unreadable binary output

```
bleakley
/etc/apt/sources.list.d
≈:≈ ls
atareao-atareao-trusty.list.save  spotify.list.save

bleakley
/etc/apt/sources.list.d
≈:≈ cat atareao-atareao-trusty.list.save 
cat: atareao-atareao-trusty.list.save: Input/output error
```

The `spotify.list` is binary, too.

How do I go about getting my `source.list` back in order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Remove the useless files

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/apt/*.save
   sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.save
   ```
2. Create a new `sources.list`

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc)-backports main universe multiverse restricted"
   sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc)-updates main universe multiverse restricted"
   sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc)-security main multiverse restricted universe"
   sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main multiverse restricted universe"
   ```
3. Refresh and upgrade

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```