# Ubuntu 16 apt get update very slow / not working

Tags: apt, 16.04

I have some issues regarding `apt-get update`. When I run the command on the terminal everytime it stops after fetiching the repos and won't continue even if I wait about an hour.

I have already tried the following proposed solutions:

- [apt-get update very slow, stuck at "Waiting for headers"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156650/apt-get-update-very-slow-stuck-at-waiting-for-headers)
- [Please Help! sudo apt-get update error (ubuntu 16.04 lts version)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769925/please-help-sudo-apt-get-update-error-ubuntu-16-04-lts-version)
- [problem with sources list, apt-get not working properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/703923/problem-with-sources-list-apt-get-not-working-properly)

However none of them seem to work for me. I would like to tell you more but there aren't any error messages displayed. The command executes as usual but then just stops without any warning. By saying "stops" I mean it prompts `Fetched 9.139 kB in 1 min 13 s (124 kB/s)` and no new line is shown. (so I am unable to invoke new commands until I hit `ctrl + c`.)

**Edit:**
As marked correctly the problem was already solved here [apt-get is stuck at "Fetched XXKb in XXsec"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774918/apt-get-is-stuck-at-fetched-xxkb-in-xxsec). I am sorry for not having seen this.

Comment: It "stops", is "slow", it "doesn't work", which is ti?